# get data from all tables having same column name and same data structure PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have one MySql database with 4000 tables. All the tables have same data structure. I want to retrieve data from one column "name" which is inside all the tables. I want to list all that data.

I had searched through google, stack overflow and many more resources. But I don't find any specific answer to do this without join or union. As I don't want to write that 4000 names in query. Is there any general query to do it fast. I think that might be possible to get data using information schema table but I don't know how.

As I know how to select tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('Product')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

But I don't know query to get data out of them.
Thank You.

Comment: if you don't want  type the  4000 name you can build automatically server side  using a procedural language the related  string of code for query starting form you select of tables ..

Comment: can you please write this procedure

Comment: SO is not a coding service  ...  you should write the procedure and we can  help you if you have errors ..

Answer (score 0):

You have php tag. So I think you can easily get your data in php.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
    //Get all table name
    $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('name') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='ai'");
    // build your query string 
    $query = ' ';
    foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $table) {
        $query .= "SELECT DISTINCT name from $table[0]  UNION ";
    }
    $queryWithoutLastWord = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $query);
    // execute your final query 
    $sth1 = $dbh->query($queryWithoutLastWord);
    // Now build your expected array
    $names = [];
    foreach ($sth1->fetchAll() as $name) {
        $names[] =  $name['name'];
    }
    print_r($names);
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: hello Imran, this code is throwing error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /home/IdidODiw/public_html/getalltables.php on line 16"

Comment: that mean you don't get any value from you query. please verify your query make sure it has data. you can dump like `$sth->count()` or `$sth1->count()` before `fetchAll()`